# Did Ready Player One have to get licenses for the usage of all its video game characters?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, licensing

*Ready Player One* is a recent book and upcoming movie that makes heavy usage of famous (and less famous) characters from video games (also movies and shows). Did the book have to get permissions and license from the copyright holders of all those creators? Would the upcoming movie have had to get fresh licenses for its usage? This sounds like it would be prohibitively expensive since they use many extremely popular characters.

Comment: Why do you think a multimillion dollar budget would find licensing to be prohibitively expensive?

Comment: @Nij Because I would speculate that the licenses for extensive usage of extremely famous characters would be very expensive. And they still need to pay for all the CGI, salaries, etc that a normal movie needs.

Comment: *Very* expensive is not *prohibitively* expensive.

Comment: @Nij If you can post an answer showing the details of how you arrived at 'very expensive' instead of 'prohibitively' expensive, I would gladly accept it :).

Comment: You can't presuppose that it's prohibitively expensive and then require evidence otherwise to accept it. That's not how burdens of proof work.

Comment: @Nij This isn't a court of law. If you have evidence to support any claim I would love to hear it. I have my presumptions and I would gladly see your evidence based answer no matter which way it goes. Also please note that the core of my question is not about cost, its about licensing requirements. Don't miss the forest through the trees.

Comment: No, it's a venue of Q&A where presumption should be justified or expected to receive disdain. Presuming that something is the case when that's neither likely nor reasonable based on similar cases isn't a great way of putting information in questions.

Comment: @Nij justification: licenses are expensive. Licenses for big names are very expensive. Very many licenses for very many big names will very very expensive. Doing it twice for a book and a movie is very very very expensive. Can we move on to more interesting things now?

Answer (score 3):

> Did the book have to get permissions and license from the copyright
>   holders of all those creators?

Probably not. This probably wouldn't have counted as a covered derivative work entitled to copyright protection and might have amounted to fair use with just mention in the text of a book

> Would the upcoming movie have had to get fresh licenses for its usage?

Yes. It almost certainly did, probably at some considerable expense (although the producers may have already owned the rights to many of them) and there were probably some editorial changes in the characters made as a result of the negotiations to replace expensive licensor demands with less expensive characters.

Also, keep in mind that contracts can be creative and often are in the financing of movies. The license was likely for a percentage of profits rather than a flat dollar amount, which was budgeted to be reasonable. No license means no inclusion in the movie and the loss of exposure if not included is an incentive to deal in addition to the license fee as exposure may increase the value of the licensed property if the movie is good.